# If I see a phone under Other Devices in Windows' Computers and Devices menu, is it connected to my network?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, cellular

I see a phone that is definitely NOT mine under Computers and Devices, as I don't own an HTC One. Does this mean it is connected to my network, or that it has WiFi capability and my computer's network card detected its presence?

Comment: Connected,  no; detected, yes

Comment: @Sathya Great, thank you. I couldn't find a site that explains this!